# Android Signal R - calling Method with parameters

Tags: java, android, .net, signalr, chat

Hi I'am developing and chat application, Therefore I am using a SignalR Android SDK - [Link Here](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/tree/master/signalr-client-test-integration-android).

I am able to get connected to the server. But I am unable to call a hub method **GetIncomingChatQueue** and receive it's response.

**Service:**

```
public class SignalRService extends Service {
    private HubConnection mHubConnection;
    private HubProxy mHubProxy;
    private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message
    private final LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public SignalRService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("Broadcast service", "Inside oncreate  - service");
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("Broadcast service", "service start  - service");
        int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startSignalR();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mHubConnection.stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Return the communication channel to the service.
        Log.d("Broadcast service", "onBind  - service");
        startSignalR();
        return (IBinder) mBinder;
    }

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SignalRService getService() {
            // Return this instance of SignalRService so clients can call public methods
            return SignalRService.this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * method for clients (activities)
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("zupportdesk", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String ProfileId = prefs.getString("ProfileId", "Not defined");
        String profileToken = prefs.getString("profileToken", "Not defined");

        Log.d("Broadcast service", "Inside send message - service");
        //String SERVER_METHOD_SEND = "checkWebServiceStatus";
        String SERVER_METHOD_SEND = "GetIncomingChatQueue("+ProfileId+","+profileToken+")";
        //mHubProxy.invoke(SERVER_METHOD_SEND, message);
        mHubProxy.invoke(SERVER_METHOD_SEND, message);
    }

    private void startSignalR() {
        // Create a new console logger
                Logger logger = new Logger() {

                    @Override
                    public void log(String message, LogLevel level) {
                        Log.d("Log Message : ", message);
                    }
                };

                // Connect to the server
                HubConnection conn = new HubConnection("https://MY DOMAIN HERE/", "", true, logger);

                // Create the hub proxy
                HubProxy proxy = conn.createHubProxy("chatHub");

                proxy.subscribe(new Object() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    public void messageReceived(String name, String message) {
                        Log.d("Log Message : ", name + ": " + message);
                    }
                });

                // Subscribe to the error event
                conn.error(new ErrorCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

                // Subscribe to the connected event
                conn.connected(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("CONNECTED");
                    }
                });

                // Subscribe to the closed event
                conn.closed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("DISCONNECTED");
                    }
                });

                // Start the connection
                conn.start()
                        .done(new Action<Void>() {

                            @Override
                            public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                                System.out.println("Done Connecting!");
                            }
                        });

                // Subscribe to the received event
                conn.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMessageReceived(JsonElement json) {
                        System.out.println("RAW received message: " + json.toString());
                    }
                });
    }
```

**Activity:**

```
class Chats extends NavigationLiveo implements OnItemClickListener {

    private final Context mContext = this;
    private SignalRService mService;
    private boolean mBound = false;

    private HelpLiveo mHelpLiveo;

    @Override
    public void onInt(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // User Information
        this.userName.setText("K.sathyabaman");
        this.userEmail.setText("sathya@rfgdgfdfgffdg.com");
        this.userPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.baman);
        this.userBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_user_background_first);

        // Creating items navigation
        mHelpLiveo = new HelpLiveo();
        mHelpLiveo.add(getString(R.string.chats), R.drawable.ic_inbox_black_24dp, 7);
        mHelpLiveo.addSeparator(); //Item separator
        mHelpLiveo.addSubHeader(getString(R.string.sub_menu)); //Item subHeader
        mHelpLiveo.add(getString(R.string.visitors), R.drawable.ic_star_black_24dp);
        mHelpLiveo.add(getString(R.string.operators), R.drawable.ic_send_black_24dp);
        mHelpLiveo.addNoCheck(getString(R.string.transcripts), R.drawable.ic_drafts_black_24dp);
        mHelpLiveo.addNoCheck(getString(R.string.canned_responses), R.drawable.ic_drafts_black_24dp);
        mHelpLiveo.addNoCheck(getString(R.string.feedback), R.drawable.ic_drafts_black_24dp);
        mHelpLiveo.addNoCheck(getString(R.string.aboutUs), R.drawable.ic_drafts_black_24dp);
        mHelpLiveo.addSeparator(); //Item separator



        //{optional} - Header Customization - method customHeader
        //View mCustomHeader = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_header_user, this.getListView(), false);
        //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mCustomHeader.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        with(this).startingPosition(2) //Starting position in the list
                .addAllHelpItem(mHelpLiveo.getHelp())
                //{optional} - List Customization "If you remove these methods and the list will take his white standard color"
                //.selectorCheck(R.drawable.selector_check) //Inform the background of the selected item color
                //.colorItemDefault(R.color.nliveo_blue_colorPrimary) //Inform the standard color name, icon and counter
                .colorItemSelected(R.color.nliveo_blue_colorPrimary) //State the name of the color, icon and meter when it is selected
                //.colorLineSeparator(R.color.nliveo_transparent) //Inform the color of the subheader line

                //{optional} - SubHeader Customization
                //.colorNameSubHeader(R.color.nliveo_blue_colorPrimary)
                //.colorLineSeparator(R.color.nliveo_green_colorPrimaryDark)

                //.removeFooter()
                .footerItem(R.string.settings, R.drawable.ic_settings_black_24dp)

                //{optional} - Second footer
                //.footerSecondItem(R.string.settings, R.drawable.ic_settings_black_24dp)

                //{optional} - Header Customization
                //.customHeader(mCustomHeader)

                //{optional} - Footer Customization
                //.footerNameColor(R.color.nliveo_blue_colorPrimary)
                //.footerIconColor(R.color.nliveo_blue_colorPrimary)

                //.footerSecondNameColor(R.color.nliveo_blue_colorPrimary)
                //.footerSecondIconColor(R.color.nliveo_blue_colorPrimary)

                //.footerBackground(R.color.nliveo_white)

                //{optional} - Remove color filter icon
                //.removeColorFilter()

                .setOnClickUser(onClickPhoto)
                .setOnPrepareOptionsMenu(onPrepare)
                .setOnClickFooter(onClickFooter)

                //{optional} - Second footer
                //.setOnClickFooterSecond(onClickFooter)
                .build();

        int position = this.getCurrentPosition();
        this.setElevationToolBar(position != 2 ? 15 : 0);




        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(mContext, SignalRService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        sendMessage();


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void sendMessage() {
        Log.d("Main Activity : ", "Inside sendMessage start - Activity ");
        if (mBound) {
            // Call a method from the SignalRService.
            // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
            // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
            String message = "hi sathya , This is a message";
            mService.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService()
     */
    private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            Log.d("Main Activity : ", "Inside service connected - Activity ");
            // We've bound to SignalRService, cast the IBinder and get SignalRService instance
            SignalRService.LocalBinder binder = (SignalRService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Fragment mFragment;
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        switch (position){
            case 2:
                mFragment = new ViewPagerFragment();
                break;

            default:
                mFragment = MainFragment.newInstance(mHelpLiveo.get(position).getName());
                break;
        }

        if (mFragment != null){
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mFragment).commit();
        }

        setElevationToolBar(position != 2 ? 15 : 0);
    }

    private OnPrepareOptionsMenuLiveo onPrepare = new OnPrepareOptionsMenuLiveo() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu, int position, boolean visible) {
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onClickPhoto = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onClickPhoto :D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            closeDrawer();
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onClickFooter = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Settings.class));
            closeDrawer();
        }
    };
```

**Response I get:**

```
08-23 12:28:08.492 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: serverSentEvents - Read the response content by line
08-23 12:28:08.492 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: serverSentEvents - Found new data: data: initialized
08-23 12:28:08.492 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: serverSentEvents - Initialization message found
08-23 12:28:08.500 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: serverSentEvents - Found new data: data: {"C":"s-0,5482","S":1,"M":[]}
08-23 12:28:08.500 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: serverSentEvents - Trigger onData: {"C":"s-0,5482","S":1,"M":[]}
08-23 12:28:08.500 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: HubConnection - Received data: 
08-23 12:28:08.500 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: MessageId received: s-0,5482
08-23 12:28:08.500 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: Initialization message received
08-23 12:28:16.471 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: serverSentEvents - Found new data: data: {}
08-23 12:28:16.471 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: serverSentEvents - Trigger onData: {}
08-23 12:28:16.471 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: HubConnection - Received data: 
08-23 12:28:26.495 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: serverSentEvents - Found new data: data: {}
08-23 12:28:26.495 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: serverSentEvents - Trigger onData: {}
08-23 12:28:26.495 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: HubConnection - Received data: 
08-23 12:28:36.525 8573-8782/baman.lankahomes.lk.zupportdeskchatsystem D/Log Message :: serverSentEvents - Found new data: data: {}
```

Can some one help me to call the specific hub method and get response from the hub.